# What's so special about the forgetful functor from G-rep to Vect?

Tags: tannakian-category, ct.category-theory, rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

The following is some version of Tannaka-Krein theory, and is reasonably well-known:

> Let $G$ be a group (in Set is all I care about for now), and $G\text{-Rep}$ the category of all $G$-modules (over some field $\mathbb K$, say).  It is a fairly structured category (complete, cocomplete, abelian, $\mathbb K$-enriched, ...) and in particular carries a symmetric tensor product $\otimes$.  The forgetful functor $\operatorname{Forget}: G\text{-Rep} \to \text{Vect}$ respects all of this structure, and in particular is (symmetric) monoidal.  Let $\operatorname{End}_\otimes(\operatorname{Forget})$ denote the monoid of monoidal natural transformations of $\operatorname{Forget}$.  Then it is a group, and there is a canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{End}_\otimes(\operatorname{Forget}) \cong G$.

The following is probably also reasonably well-known, but I don't know it myself:

> Let $G$, etc., be as above, but suppose that we have forgotten what $G$ the category $G\text{-Rep}$ came from, and in particular forgot, at least momentarily, the data of the forgetful functor.  We can nevertheless recover it, because in fact $\operatorname{Forget}$ is the unique-up-to-isomorphism ADJECTIVES functor $G\text{-Rep} \to \text{Vect}$.

My question is: what are the words that should go in place of "ADJECTIVES" above?  Certainly "linear, continuous, cocontinuous, monoidal" are all reasonable words, although my intuition has been that I can drop "cocontinuous" from the list.  But even with all these words, I don't see how to prove the uniqueness.  If I had to guess, I would guess that the latter claim is a result of Deligne's, although I don't read French well enough to skim a bunch of his papers and find it.  Any pointers to the literature?

Comment: Quick summary of the answers below: there are no such "ADJECTIVES" possible, and the claim is false.

Comment: However, if you're working over the complex numbers and include the adjective symmetric then there is such a result and it's proved in Deligne-Milne.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If $G$ is an affine algebraic group (for example a finite group), then the category of $k$-linear cocontinuous symmetric monoidal functors from $\mathsf{Rep}(G)$ to $\mathsf{Vect}_k$ is equivalent to the category of $G$-torsors over $k$. In particular, not every such functor needs to be isomorphic to the identity. For example, if $k'$ is finite Galois extension of k with Galois group $G$, then the functor $F(V) = (V \otimes_{k} k')^{G}$ will satisfy all the axioms you will think to write down, but is not isomorphic to the identity functor.

Comment: Interesting!  But this is not something I'm used to. In non-algebraic-geometry land, all G-torsors for a given group G are isomorphic, almost by definition.  How is the definition different in affine-algebraic land that allows for non-isomorphic torsors-over-k?

Comment: So, I'm going to think out loud while I do the simplest example. Let $k=\mathbb R$, $k'=\mathbb C$, `$G=\{\pm 1\}$`, then $G\text{-rep}=\text{Vect}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2=1)$, so that $\epsilon$ is the nontrivial one-dimensional G-rep, and as a G-rep $\mathbb C=1+\epsilon$. Then your functor is $(a+b\epsilon)\mapsto((a+b\epsilon)(1+\epsilon))^{\epsilon=0}=(a+b+\epsilon(a+b))^{\epsilon=0}=(a+b)$, which is isomorphic object-by-object to the forgetful functor $(a+b\epsilon)\mapsto(a+b)$. Moreover, there's not enough room for morphisms to be interesting. I think these functors are isomorphic.

Comment: In this context, a $G$-torsor means a $k$-scheme with an action of $G$, which is ($G$-equivariantly) isomorphic to $G$ over some extension field of $k$. So if $k'$ is a Galois extension of k with Galois group $G$, then the spectrum of $k'$ is a $G$-torsor (since $k' \otimes_k k' \simeq k^G$ by virtue of the Galois assumption).

Comment: The isomorphism you describe is not an isomorphism of symmetric monoidal functors.

To see this, let $k^G$ denote the regular representation of $G$, regarded as commutative algebra via pointwise multiplication. If F: Rep(G) -> Vect(k) is any symmetric monoidal functor, then $F(k^G)$ will inherit the structure of a commutative algebra. In the above example, $F(k^G)$ is the space of $G$-invariants in $k'^{G}$, where
$G$ is acting both by permuting the factors and by Galois symmetries.Evaluation at the identity element of $G$ determines an isomorphism of this algebra with $k'$,which is not $k^G$.

Comment: But maybe this is a "Law of Small Numbers" problem.

Comment: Oh, great.  Thanks.  So this is the same thing that David Jordan pointed out, which is that the symmetric structure is important too.  They are isomorphic as monoidal functors.

Comment: No, wait, what I said is still false. They're isomorphic as functors, but not as monoidal functors. The point is that a monoidal functor is a functor along with some extra structure, required to satisfy a condition. It is then symmetric if it satisfies another condition --- symmetric monoidal functors are not extra data on top of monoidal functors (symmetric monoidal structures on a category are extra data). Similarly, a monoidal natural transformation is a natural transformation satisfying some condition. But once it satisfies this, being symmetric is not an extra condition.

Comment: Isomorphic to my last comment: your point above was that $k^G$ and $k'$ aren't isomorphic as algebras.  That they are both commutative doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 11):

One needs to be careful.  One cannot recover the group $G$ from the tensor category alone, but only with the data of category, fiber functor.  There are examples of non-isomorphic (finite, even) groups with equivalent categories of representations.  For instance, see Pasquale Zito's answer to this question:

[Finite groups with the same character table](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/500/finite-groups-with-the-same-character-table)

However, as is discussed in the paper Zito links to, remembering the symmetry on the categories recovers the group, up to isomorphism.  I'm not sure who it's due to.

Comment: The last sentence probably follows from Deligne's theorem which says that a symmetric tensor category satisfying certain growth properties in the length of its objects under iterated tensor product is necessarily RepG for a super group G, and which group it is is determined by the symmetric structure.  A very nice exposition, in English, is here:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401347

Comment: Oh, OK!  So I should demand that my functor to Vect be _symmetric monoidal_.  The Ostrik paper is a nice one.

Comment: Presumably supergroups appear here for the same kind of reason that supergroupoids appear in '2-Hilbert Spaces' http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9609018, e.g., where Baez and Dolan prove "a generalized Doplicher-Roberts theorem stating that every symmetric 2-$H^{\ast}$-algebra is equivalent to the category $Rep(G)$ of continuous unitary finite-dimensional representations of some compact supergroupoid $G$."

Comment: Direct link to @pasqualezito's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/504).